# .net dll not working in PB 12

Tags: c#, powerbuilder

I have a .net project with 2 methods. Once I build the application and give the dll to PowerBuilder 12 folks, after adding the dll in the project it is not showing the methods.
How do I build the .net project so that all the methods are visible in PowerBuilder 12.

thanks

Comment: Are the methods and their enclosing class(es) `public`?

Comment: All are public methods and other .net applications are using this dll too

Comment: Does PowerBuilder 12 target the same .NET version that you've compiled the dll against?

Comment: Need more info. Are the PowerBuilder guys using PB 12.Net or PB 12 Classic. PB 12 Classic can't use .NET Dlls unless you use COM.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old but there are a fair number of views so I will take the time to answer it.

There are really only three main requirements.

1. Make the .NET method "Public"
2. Make the .NET enclosing class "Public"
3. Use the assembly in the correct .NET version application (e.g. PB11 = .NET2.5; PB12 = .NET3.0; PB12.5 = .NET4.0, etc.)

For complete instructions on making PB.NET methods available in .NET and making .NET methods available in PB.NET you can check out "[Using .NET Assembly Methods in PowerBuilder.NET and vice-versa](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/using-net-assembly-methods-in-powerbuilder-net-and-vice-versa/)"